# What are the advantages of using tf.train.SequenceExample over tf.train.Example for variable length features?

Tags: tensorflow

Recently I read [this](http://www.wildml.com/2016/08/rnns-in-tensorflow-a-practical-guide-and-undocumented-features) guide on undocumented featuers in TensorFlow, as I needed to pass variable length sequences as input. However, I found the protocol for `tf.train.SequenceExample` relatively confusing (especially due to lack of documentation), and managed to build an input pipe using `tf.train.Example` just fine instead.

Are there any advantages to using `tf.train.SequenceExample`? Using the standard example protocol when there is a dedicated one for variable length sequences seems like a cheat, but does it bear any consequence?

Comment: undocumented features'  implementation may change rapidly and other attributes in near future; not recommended to use till proper documentations. So better to stick with `tf.train.Example`

Answer (score 18):

Here are the definitions of the `Example` and `SequenceExample` protocol buffers, and all the protos they may contain:

```java
message BytesList { repeated bytes value = 1; }
message FloatList { repeated float value = 1 [packed = true]; }
message Int64List { repeated int64 value = 1 [packed = true]; }
message Feature {
    oneof kind {
        BytesList bytes_list = 1;
        FloatList float_list = 2;
        Int64List int64_list = 3;
    }
};
message Features { map<string, Feature> feature = 1; };
message Example { Features features = 1; };

message FeatureList { repeated Feature feature = 1; };
message FeatureLists { map<string, FeatureList> feature_list = 1; };
message SequenceExample {
  Features context = 1;
  FeatureLists feature_lists = 2;
};
```

An `Example` contains a `Features`, which contains a mapping from feature name to `Feature`, which contains either a `bytes` list, or a `float` list or an `int64` list.

A `SequenceExample` also contains a `Features`, but it also contains a `FeatureLists`, which contains a mapping from list name to `FeatureList`, which contains a list of `Feature`. So it can do everything an `Example` can do, and more. But do you really need that extra functionality? What does it do?

Since each `Feature` contains a list of values, a `FeatureList` is a list of lists. And that's the key: if you need lists of lists of values, then you need `SequenceExample`.

For example, if you handle text, you can represent it as one big string:

```py
from tensorflow.train import BytesList

BytesList(value=[b"This is the first sentence. And here's another."])
```

Or you could represent it as a list of words and tokens:

```py
BytesList(value=[b"This", b"is", b"the", b"first", b"sentence", b".", b"And", b"here",
                 b"'s", b"another", b"."])
```

Or you could represent each sentence separately. That's where you would need a list of lists:

```py
from tensorflow.train import BytesList, Feature, FeatureList

s1 = BytesList(value=[b"This", b"is", b"the", b"first", b"sentence", b"."])
s2 = BytesList(value=[b"And", b"here", b"'s", b"another", b"."])
fl = FeatureList(feature=[Feature(bytes_list=s1), Feature(bytes_list=s2)])
```

Then create the `SequenceExample`:

```py
from tensorflow.train import SequenceExample, FeatureLists

seq = SequenceExample(feature_lists=FeatureLists(feature_list={
    "sentences": fl
}))
```

And you can serialize it and perhaps save it to a TFRecord file.

```py
data = seq.SerializeToString()
```

Later, when you read the data, you can parse it using `tf.io.parse_single_sequence_example()`.

Answer (score 4):

The link you provided lists some benefits. You can see how [parse_single_sequence_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/parse_single_sequence_example) is used here  https://github.com/tensorflow/magenta/blob/master/magenta/common/sequence_example_lib.py

If you managed to get the data into your model with `Example`, it should be fine. `SequenceExample` just gives a little more structure to your data and some utilities for working with it.