# How to save list of lists of varying length in a TFRecord?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I have a dataset which is made up of nested sequences, so for example one data point looks like this:

```
p1 = [[1,1,1], [2,2], [3,3,3]]
```

but another data point could look like this:

```
p2 = [[1,1], [2,2,2,2,2]]
```

I am not sure how I can save lists of lists in TFRecords as all the examples I found only save **non-nested** lists of varying length. I plan to then uses padded_batch to create 3D tensors of the shape 
`[batch size, max number of lists, max number of tokens in a list]`

Answer (score 1):

One option is to just store each value sequentially. For instance, your first example would be stored as `[1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3]`. To reproduce the original sequence, you can store the original lengths as well - `[3,2,3]` and then reconstruct in preprocessing. I recommend padding the nested sequences from the start so that you can go to/from flat/nested with a simple reshape operation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit late for answering, though I think for those who need it there's a more native way than flattening sequences as proposed by @Cory Nezin.

1. In your particular case, I think you may want to use `RaggedTensors` that can be written in TFRecords natively and read with [RaggedFeature](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/RaggedFeature). In a case like yours where you have a 2D RaggedTensor, you need to store values of the tensor as long with row-splits (e.g.) and read it like (you'll find more information [in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/RaggedFeature#examples)):

```py
tf.io.RaggedFeature(value_key="value_serialization", dtype=tf.int64, partitions=[
        tf.io.RaggedFeature.RowSplits("row_split_serialization")])
```

2. If you had only the number of sequences that may vary but the internal vector is of fixed dimension (not your case here but yet worth mentionning). You may want to use [SequenceExample](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/train/SequenceExample) as the proto for writing in a `TFRecord` and decode with [parse_single_sequence_example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/io/parse_single_sequence_example). It's a bit hard to sort this out due to lack of documentation though but you may find useful [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45634450/what-are-the-advantages-of-using-tf-train-sequenceexample-over-tf-train-example).

Comment: How can we write ragged tensors to TFRecords using `tf.train.Feature` and `tf.train.Example`? Thanks